# Detecting unknown location hashes in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am working on a jQuery Mobile app that needs to show content based on a reference in the URL  location hash, e.g.

http://theapp/page.html#key1234

Obviously, jQuery Mobile will search through the page looking for an internal page with id "key1234". It will fail and then show a blank page. What I'd like to do is capture an event when a URL with an unknown hash is entered, and then dynamically generate a matching page for it.

I'd like to do it this was so that users can have short memorable URLs.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

$( document ).bind( "pageloadfailed", function( event, data ){

});